# Am I still able to produce a MRE without having a Python installed in my computer now?

Tags: discussion

I posted a question with very clear description and screenshots of what I was asking for, but it still got deleted because of some MRE requirement.

Since the requirement about posting a question seems very strict here, do I have to always produce a MRE for my question? Do I always need Python installed to make one?  or I might expect Stack Overflow has some built-in function to run some Python coding and produce result (which I can use as MRE) instantly? Just like DataCamp?

Comment: This belongs on [meta], but the answer is yes, an MRE is needed, regardless of where you're posting from. We don't accept screenshots of code or errors because images can't be indexed or searched, and they don't work with screen readers or for people with visual impairments.

Comment: A) Your question was not as straightforward as you think it was B) If you can't run python code to provide an example, then how can you run python code to test the answers you're given? C) Without a MRE, we don't know what you've tried based on your own research, so we don't know how to best help you D) Without sample data in the text of the question, I would have to transcribe the picture to be able to test my ideas for solutions, _or_ I could answer 2-3 other questions that had examples in less time than that would take

Comment: Ok thanks and fair enough. I have two laptops and I only have Python installed in my work laptop while I ask questions using my home laptop (which doesn't have Python) after finishing work. But I have now installed Python in my home laptop and am looking into making MRE for my original question.

Comment: You say *"got deleted because of some MRE requirement"*, but wasn't it you who deleted it?

Comment: The original question was closed by moderator anyway so I deleted it.

Comment: I have now run df.head(10).to_clipboard(sep=',', index=True) and pasted the result into the Body of my question that I am about to post. But before that do I have to highlight the result (i.e. the look of the df) and press Ctrl+K? It looks a bit nicer but still not too nice.

Comment: You do know the existence of online IDEs? Like the one I used [here to help another user with their python question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354016/158100). That answer contains advice I could replicate here in an answer.

Comment: You could also just install Python on your home computer. Shouldn't take more than a few minutes. If you're going to be asking questions from there, seems like a prudent thing to do.

Comment: Or, you could use repl.it. Note that repl doesn't have support for a lot of external modules. For that you would need to download python, something that shouldn't take too long.

Comment: [MRE ~ Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) (glossary) → [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please research before considering asking a question. Like this one. Report your research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by rene there are online Python IDEs that you can use to verify your MRE. Currently there is no such service directly available on stackoverflow.com.

In the cases where you do not need an MRE (the really simple cases like "How  do I append an element to a list in Python?") or where you need one but it can be verified with an online service or you can use another computer with Python installed you do not need to have Python installed on your computer. If you make an MRE however, make sure that it's correct, i.e. run it at least once somewhere. In case you need certain packages that are not available in online Python IDEs, please install Python on your computer. It's free.

While I think it's a rare case currently, I see future potential in this question. There is surely an ongoing trend to move to cloud based computing, this question could become relevant.

Answer (score 4):

If you're posting a question, you're expected to have all of the components of the question contained in the question when it's asked.  If this means that you need to have Python installed to be sure that your example is minimal and will run if some random person comes along and tries to solve it, then **you should have Python installed** if nothing else so that we can help you out.

I won't get into the specifics of whether or not you can or can't have Python installed; if you can't get us in context to the environment that you're running in, then don't be surprised if your question is shut down.

Answer (score 3):

You're expected to provide all details required for your question to be understandable. If you're asking about a problem with code you've written, we need to actually be able to see the code (or [no one will be able to help](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)).

Think about it this way: if all we have is a description of code, all we'll be able to do is speculate as to what your problem is. Almost by definition, if you're posting here, you don't know what the problem is (or, at least, you don't know how to fix the problem). What if the problem is much different than what you thought?